# How to open a new command prompt with subprocess.run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to open a new command prompt and resume in my desktop app (my app has an "open command prompt here" button). But I cant get it to work: Either the execution of my app halts until I close the command window or the command window just pipes and nothing is shown.
This some of what I've tried:

```
# does nothing, just the execution halts
process = subprocess.run(['cmd.exe'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

# Opens the cmd prompt, but execution halts until I close it.
process = subprocess.run(['start'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

So how to do this with the subprocess module? I don't want to use legacy functions, the doc states, that I should use this module instead of os.system and os.spawn* (I'm using Python 3.5)

Comment: is the typo intentional? `['start']`, ...

Comment: @RápliAndrás ops, no

Comment: @sydd Does that duplicate address your issue? It sounds like you just want a non-blocking subprocess call. Is that correct?

Comment: @skrrgwasme Kinda... I am opening lots of stuff with a subprocess.run(), I dont understand why can I open e.g. windows Explorer and its non-blocking, and why cant I do the same with a command prompt

Comment: @sydd That does sound odd, but I suspect it's related to windows explorer, not your Python code. `subprocess.run()` is indeed a blocking call, so it's explorer that's doing something odd. Your code is doing what it's supposed to do.